# "myWebView can not be resolved"

Tags: javascript, java, browser, webview

I'm trying to create a webview application by the platform called sketchware, which is an application available in the play store that allows you to create your own application. Well, I created a webview application, which loads the page from my site, except that my site has pop-up advertisements, which appear out of nowhere as you click somewhere on the page, and that's what I want the webview application does that it open the links of the site pop-up ads (when they are clicked) in the external browser (type Chrome) and only open the links within the webview app that are based on my own site, own pages of my site, not the pages of advertisements when they are clicked. So I was wondering how I can add this code correctly in my webview application made in sketchware.

I put this code in sketchware, but it always gives an error at the time I'm going to build the application to create it, and I do not know how to fix that error that it is giving. There are always two massages of this here: "myWebView can not be resolved".

But I do not know what to do to try to solve this code for it to work. I do not understand virtually anything, and I do not know how to fix this code so do not give that mistake anymore. Can anyone help a beginner like me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contains("http://www.youradress.com")) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        } else {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(intent);
           return true;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Don't post (links to) an image of text! Instead add the text itself as an [edit] to the question. BTW - is this Android based? Which GUI component toolkit is being used here? General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).